# How can I load data of one column into another column in the same table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In my table I have a column as storage_date with value as 16-09-2022 and I need to create 3 columns as YEAR,MONTH,DAY in same table and I want to load data for these three columns from storage_date column as 2022 for YEAR , 09 for MONTH and 16 for DAY

Comment: update the new columns with extract see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions?hl=de but hinestly why have redundat information in a table, you can EXTRACT all needed information at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Assuming its Oracle DB this should work:

```
update tbl 
set dd = extract(day from storage_date), yyyy = extract(year from storage_date), mm = extract(month from storage_date)
```

From the docs
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm

Comment: there's a code format button you can apply to your answer to improve it

Comment: better formating

Comment: Why are you assuming it's Oracle? The question is tagged with Google BigQuery.